# Best way to perform error handling using modules in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, api-design

I'm pretty new to Rails and back-end API developement so excuse me if I misuse a concept or so. Right now I'm attempting to refactor a large amount of conditional error handling code that is sprinkled around the code base and move towards using an explicit list of rescued exceptions that's mixed into the API controller by including it in as a module. This will allow me to attach custom, but arbitrary, codes to each exception caught, so long as we use the bang alternatives for active record methods, and the error handling code can live in one place. So far, for the error handling module, I have something like this:

```
# app/lib/error/error_handling.rb
module Error
  module ErrorHandling
    def self.included(klass)
      klass.class_eval do
        rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |e|
          respond(:record_not_found, 404, e.to_s)
        end
        rescue_from ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError do |e|
          respond(e.error, 422, e.to_s)
        end
        rescue_from ActiveController::ParameterMissing do |e|
          response(:unprocessable_entitry, 422, e.to_s)
        end
        rescue_from ActiveModel::ValidationError do |e|
          response(e.error, 422, e.to_s)
        end
        rescue_from CustomApiError do |e|
          respond(e.error, e.status, e.message.to_s)
        end
        rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do
          respond(:forbidden, 401, "current user isn't authorized for that")
        end
        rescue_from StandardError do |e|
          respond(:standard_error, 500, e.to_s)
        end
      end
    end

    private

    def respond(_error, _status, _message)
      render "layouts/api/errors", status: _status
    end
  end
end
```

Where `layouts/api/errors` is a view built using jbuilder.
In the `ApiController` we have:

```
# app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb
module Api
  class ApiController < ApplicationController
    include Error::ErrorHandling

    attr_reader :active_user

    layout "api/application"

    before_action :authenticate_by_token!
    before_action :set_uuid_header

    respond_to :json
    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?

    private

    ...

end
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. Running tests shows that the private methods are not being loaded at all and are considered undefined!

To be more specific, here are the errors emitted:

```
uninitialized constant Error::ErrorHandling::ActiveController
```

and

```
undefined local variable or method `active_user' for Api::FooController
```

Where `active_user` is an attribute that is set inside of an instance variable by a method named `set_active_user`. Which is obviously not being called.

However the `ErrorHandling` module is being evaluated. How could this be? Am I namespacing incorrectly or something?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on which private methods are undefined? The on in the controller or the on in the module? If possible, a stacktrace could also help.

Comment: I've updated the post. As mentioned, the module is being evaluated but I hit the an `unitialized constant` error within it, and the `undefined local variable or method` inside of the api controller, when they are actually defined. Perhaps the error in the module prevents code below the `include` from being evaluated?

Comment: I could only provide a basic pointer regarding the 'undefined method' problem. If you show the code which raises the error, I could offer more specific help.

Comment: side note usually local variables preceded by an underscore are to indicate that they are not used as in `{1: '2'}.each {|k,_v| # some code just for k}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is broken down into two parts as I believe that there are two separate problems.

**unitinalized constant error**

The error

```
uninitialized constant Error::ErrorHandling::ActiveController
```

can be fixed by changing this

```
rescue_from ActiveController::ParameterMissing do |e|
  response(:unprocessable_entitry, 422, e.to_s)
end
```

to this:

```
 rescue_from ::ActiveController::ParameterMissing do |e|
   response(:unprocessable_entitry, 422, e.to_s)
 end
```

(adding `::` in front of the `ActiveController` constant)

Constant lookup in ruby takes lexical nesting into account. As you reference the Constant within

```
module Error
  module ErrorHandling
  ...
  end
end
```

ruby will try to find the constant within this namespace if the constant is undefined before. Prepending `::` will tell ruby to ignore the nesting on constant lookup.

**undefined local method**

The error

```
undefined local variable or method `active_user' for Api::FooController
```

is raised because some code is calling the *instance* method `active_user` on the *class* `Api::FooController` where it is not defined.

Comment: Thanks, made progress. I understand more about ruby now!

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you want to read more about constant lookup you can take a look [at this page](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I was struggling with it but found the fix. To fix the issue of:

```
`undefined local variable or method `active_user' for Api::FooController`
```

You need to include extend `ActiveSupport::Concern` e.g.

```
module Error
  module ErrorHandling
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    # rest of your code
  end
end
```